How to dynamically show and require additional fields in Keycloak registration form based on user input?
Customizing Keycloak Registration Form: Dynamic Fields and Validation
I am customizing the Keycloak registration form to allow users to choose between two types during registration: Individual or Legal Entity. Based on their choice, the form should display specific fields and validate them accordingly:
If Individual is selected, display and require fields like First Name and Last Name.
If Legal Entity is selected, display and require fields like Company Name and VAT Number.
I need to ensure the following:
Client-Side Validation: The form should dynamically update to display the appropriate fields when the user switches between the two options and enforce required fields.
Server-Side Validation: Validate the submitted fields based on the user's selection to prevent incomplete or incorrect submissions.
Group Assignment: Assign the user to a group (e.g., "Individual" or "Legal Entity") based on their selection.
Specific Problem:
How can I dynamically enforce the required fields and validate the custom attributes both on the client side and the server side? Additionally, what is the recommended approach to process and validate these attributes using a Keycloak SPI or other built-in Keycloak mechanisms?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
